# Having a problem whit substringstring removing

Tags: python

So im trying to remove a substrings (numbers and special characters) from the user input and then reverse the whole input string. The number removing works fine, however the special charachter does not. Please take a look.

```
en_word = input()
x = 0
y = 0
f_character = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "!", "@", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", 
")", "-"]
while f_character[x] in en_word:
    en_word = en_word.replace(f_character[x], "")
    x += 1
print(en_word[:: -1])
```

Input

```
123o%l$leh321
```

Expected Output

```
hello
```

Actual Output

```
hel$l%o
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Your loop is breaking as soon as `x` is incremented to `3`.
Since your original input `123o%l$leh321` doesn't contain f_character[3], which is `"4"`, the `while` condition will be false.

I recommend changing your code to a `for-loop`:

```
en_word = input()
f_character = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "!", "@", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", 
")", "-"]
for char in f_character:
    en_word = en_word.replace(char, "")
print(en_word[:: -1])
```

Answer (score 4):

Your while loop will exit as soon as a letter is not inside the word - this is the case for `'4'` -all others will not be checked.

Fix:

```
en_word = "123o%l$leh321" 
y = 0
f_character = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", 
               "!", "@", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "-"]
for c in f_character:
    en_word = en_word.replace(c, "") 
print(en_word[:: -1])
```

---

There is a better way to do this, using [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) and [str.maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans):

```
replacer = str.maketrans("", "", "123456789!@$%^&*()-")
en_word = "123o%l$leh321" 

print(en_word.translate(replacer)[::-1])  # hello
```

Doku [str.maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans):

> This static method returns a translation table usable for [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate).
>
> If there is only one argument, it must be a dictionary mapping Unicode ordinals (integers) or characters (strings of length 1) to Unicode ordinals, strings (of arbitrary lengths) or None. Character keys will then be converted to ordinals.
>
> If there are two arguments, they must be strings of equal length, and in the resulting dictionary, each character in x will be mapped to the character at the same position in y. **If there is a third argument, it must be a string, whose characters will be mapped to None in the result.**

Answer (score 2):

I would use Python's `re` module to handle removing characters regular expressions are a powerful tool that will help you immesauarbly when dealing with messy human input.

as you have a list, lets escape the special chars and create a pattern.

```
import re
f_character = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "!", "@", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", 
")", "-"]

pat = '|'.join([re.escape(c) for c in f_character])
#'1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|!|@|\\$|%|\\^|\\&|\\*|\\(|\\)|\\-'

word = '123o%l$leh321'
clean_word = re.sub(pat,'',word)[::-1]
```

---

```
print(clean_word)
'hello'
```

Comment: Thank you! A little advanced for me I will make sure to look it up.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is because of: `while f_character[x] in en_word:`

You can have thé expected result by setting
    f_character = ["1", "2", "3", "%", "$"]

But for a more global result, you should change your code for something like:

```
en_word = input() 
f_character = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "!", "@","$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "-"]
en_word.translate(None, ''.join(f_character))
print(en_word[:: -1])`
```